# Using codeigniter, ajax how to fetch next records from an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I have an array

```
http://www.postano.com/api/posts.php?ak=XXXX&ts=XXXXX&sig=XXXXX&postano=12345&start=0&count=20
```

I will be fetch first 20 records initially. 
Here is the class

```
class social extends CI_Controller{
function data()
{
$start = $k;

$resultjson = $this->curl->simple_get("http://www.postano.com/api/posts.php?ak=XXXXX&ts=XXXXX&sig=XXXXX&postano=12345&start=$k&count=20");
$resultant_data = json_decode($resultjson,true);
foreach ($resultant_data as $key => $value)
     {
     //print_r($value);
     $this->load->view('feeds',$value);
     }
 }

}
```

Here feeds is my **view**.

How can i fetch next 20 records say `start or $k = 2`0 so that I can display the results from `0-20 then 21-40 and so on...`

I am trying to implement an **autoload** or **loadmore** functionality.
 **I am not using model(database) the only source is json response**

Comment: Have you had a look at the GET parameters you're sending to the service? If you'd have done, you'd have seen the `start` and `count` ones. So you might want to change the URL into something like `http://www.postano.com/api/posts.php?ak=XXXX&ts=XXXXX&sig=XXXXX&postano=12345&start=21&count=20` to get the next 20 values.

Comment: Ok if i get this will earlier 20 values persist? I mean i should show initially 20 then on clicked loadmore button i must get next 20 records below the earlier one's

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri Then you can append those divs of 20 values with new data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned over chat that you want to use AJAX, on page load have the first request you wanted. Load up your 20 results.

When you want more results, send an AJAX request and from the script that got requested curl request more products from a specified starting point and limit like Havelock mentioned, something along the lines of

```
http://www.postano.com/api/posts.php?ak=XXXX&ts=XXXXX&sig=XXXXX&postano=12345&s‌​tart=21&count=20
```

Then return the results you got form your ajax request and append it to the page if you want to keep the first 20 results that you had from page load, otherwise replace it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to pass a variable **$page** to **data() function** as argument, which will work as pagination.

And in your data() function, set

```
$start = $page*$count+1;
```

Like

In first page or first set of records i.e. from 1-20, $page will be 1.

And if ask for next list of records, set it to 2.

Comment: If the *'postano'* API doesn't support limiting/specifying which results to return, then this would be my favoured solution.

Comment: I think telling the limit of records is not better idea. Use of paging is good one, just simply tell the number of page of which the data is required. Like switching from 1st page to 4th.

Comment: I gave you a +1 but I disagree with you there; if the API natively supports limiting results then it is always going to be a preferable solution as a)it's supported natively in the API, b)you're only requesting the specific data you need - avoiding the wastage of resources.

Comment: +1 for another simple logic I agree with you but pagination concept is little boring in todays web applications right. !